# Function with parametrized type. Way to evaluate parametrized type?

Tags: c#, .net

I have a function declared like this:

```
 private static void func<t>(int x1, int x2)
 {
      //Some stuff that we don't care about
 }
```

So, inside of the function, I need a way to detect if t is boolean. I've tried:

```
if (t == typeof(bool))
```

but compiler seems to not even let you access t inside the function.

Comment: how is `t` used in your method?

Comment: I think it should be `typeof(t) == typeof(bool)`

Comment: This kind of method is called a *generic* method. Its whole purpose is to not know what exactly `T` is. You kind of want to use generics in the way they were invented to fight against.

Comment: `t` here is the compile time type. `typeof(t)` will return the `System.Type`.

Comment: I'm working with DataTables and I use the t type in the methods Field<t>("sth") and SetField<t>("sth"). The idea is that when I call this function I will say if the field we are changing is an integer, a string, a double or a boolean.

Comment: @CallumLinington I know, and in most cases I will use t and not know what t actually is. The problem is that I'm building an application that connects to Postgres database, and for some reasons C# bool and Postgres boolean are not quite compatible, so I need to treat that case in a special way,

Comment: Do yourself a favor and use `T` rather than `t` as the type parameter.  Your eyes and your mind (and everyone else who reads your code) will silently thank you as time goes on.

Comment: @Flydog57 Thx for that advice

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to say

```
if (typeof(t) == typeof(bool))
```